# Is Ash Ketchum rich?

Tags: pokemon

Ash Ketchum travels months on end sometimes years through towns and cities staying at motels and buying human food, transport, sometimes pokemon food and things (even though yes he also camps out in the wild, sometimes gets food in the wild, sometimes people make him free food and sometimes stays with people he knows for free) but he seems to buy a lot and recently in Pokemon Journeys he goes to different regions sometimes just for one day whether it be by plane, train, boat or flying mega pokemon.

Is Ash Ketchum rich?

Comment: nothing confirmed but he does have his prize winnings from several Pokémon tournaments.  And seeing brock is a gym leader and does most of the cooking before the first tournament he could be bankrolling the group. And his mother could of course wire him some money now and then

Answer (score 4):

In *[Pokemon: The Electric Tale of Pikachu](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/The_Electric_Tale_of_Pikachu)*, we learn that Ash gets a regular allowance, presumably from his mother.

[image]

And in Pokémon: Indigo League - Beauty and The Beach Ash and his friends aren't wealthy enough to pay for some damages to a restaurant. Misty is forced to enter a beauty contest to win the cash needed, which implies that Ash isn't wealthy (at least not at this point in the story).

> **Misty:** This is totally embarrassing and degrading but **we need the money.**